# what is the use of . operator at the end of variable php

Tags: php, operator-keyword

I found the following code in `http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php`

```
<?php 
function randPass($len) 
{ 
 $pw = ''; //intialize to be blank 
 for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++) 
 { 
   switch(rand(1,3)) 
   { 
     case 1: $pw.=chr(rand(48,57));  break; //0-9 
     case 2: $pw.=chr(rand(65,90));  break; //A-Z 
     case 3: $pw.=chr(rand(97,122)); break; //a-z 
   } 
 } 
 return $pw; 
} 
?> 

Example: 

<?php 
 $password = randPass(10); //assigns 10-character password 
?>
```

Could some kindly explain me the use or effect of a `.` after `$pw` .I tried looking for similar question,but could not find one.If there is any related question,plz provide link.

Thanks

Comment: You have to read the code as `$pw .= chr(...);`. `.=` is an operator.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: This is terrible way to generate random password anyway

Answer (score 1):

`.` is string concatenation.

```
$a = 'hello';
$b = 'there';
```

then

```
echo $a . $b;
```

prints

```
hellothere
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation Operator.

```
$a = "Hello ";
$a .= "World!"; 
// $a = Hello World!

$a = "Hello ";
$b = "there ";
$c = "stack ";
$d = "overflow ";
$a .= $b;
$a .= $c;
$a .= $d;
echo $a;

// $a = Hello there stack overflow
```

Comment: Why the downvote/no comment? This is definitely correct.

Comment: Indeed. Not only it was the 1st answer, it's also correct. Maybe you should flag it (if the downvote comes from another answer author, this is unfair)

Answer (score 0):

It use for Concatenation.
 When you use it like this `.=` it concatenates the values.

```
$str = '';
$str .= 'My ';
$str .= 'Name ';
$str .= 'Is ';
$str .= 'Siamak.';
echo $str;
```

Output is : `My Name Is Siamak.`

In the other cases, for example in a loop:

```
$str = '';
$i=0;
while($i<10)
{
   $str .= $i;
   $i++;
}
echo $str;
```

And output is: `123456789`

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = 'hello';
$a .= ' world';
```

Is the same as:

```
$a = 'hello';
$a = $a . ' world';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $a = "Hi!";

    $a .= " I";
    $a .= " am";
    $a .= " new";
    $a .= " to";
    $a .= " PHP & StackOverflow";

echo $a;


//echos Hi! I am new to PHP & StackOverflow
```

`.=` simply appends